# How to get minimum fee for a transaction using bitcore-lib (NodeJs)?

Tags: node.js, bitcoin, bitcore

I'm doing a transaction of BTC using bitcore-lib nodejs package. when I set 1 satoshi fee per byte it shows an error like **"Fee is too small: expected more than x but got y"**.  Is there any way to get that x value to set fee?

```
let tx = bitcore.Transaction();

tx.from(utxos);
tx.to(toAddress,sendAmountInSatoshi);
tx.change(fromAddress);
tx.fee(fee);
tx.sign(pKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure if it's part of the API specification you can use their `_estimateFee()` method:

https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-lib/blob/86583608814dfc513e675d7b853806caf9bd95e7/lib/transaction/transaction.js#L242

Answer (score -2):

If you are using the bitcoin testnet make sure to include the minimum amount of fees which is **3000 satoshis**.

You can set the fees as **low** as you want in the **livenet**, but the testnet require this as the minimum amount so as to ensure people continue mining on the testnet to *help the developer community*.

Cheers!